# Talend send tLogRow table result in tSendMail if its not empty else do nothing

Tags: java, talend

Hello guys im trying to send the results of these tLogRow using tSendMail but i dont know how to do it can anyone help please.

[image]

[image: The first tSendMail is for View folders rejections and the second one is for View files rejections]

Thank you

Comment: It's not that simple.  tLogRow is nothing more than a way to output data.  If you want an email of any substance then you'll need to process each record and build a HTML string output (or something) to then pass in as the body to the email.  There's work involved.

Answer (score 1):

tLogRow only displays data or results in the Run console to monitor data processed.

You can create output file of a result set as csv/txt/xls and send it as email attachment.